# How to set attribute to selected field?

Tags: qgis, python-2.7

I am trying to create a temporary point layer in memory using the following python code.

```
# create layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temporary_points", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()

# add fields
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("Id", QVariant.Int),
                    QgsField("Type",  QVariant.String),
                    QgsField("size", QVariant.Double)])

# add a feature
fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(10,10)))
fet.setAttributes(?)
pr.addFeatures([fet])
```

I would like to set attributes to the label "size" and not for all. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would to assign `NULL` values for all fields except the field `size`.
Searching for index of the `size` field, create an empty list and finally associate the value for the `size` field, this may be done by:

```
## get the index of the "size" field
index = pr.fieldNameIndex("size")
## create an empty list-of-None
attrMap = [None] * len(pr.fields())
## I am assigning the value 10 to the size field
attrMap[index] = 10 

fet.setAttributes(attrMap)
```